# This version of android studio is incompatible with the gradle version used.Try disabling the instant run

Tags: android-studio, build

I am able to build the app properly, but when I run it I get this error:

```
This version of android studio is incompatible with the gradle version used.Try disabling the instant run
```

Comment: fyi:i have disabled instant run

Comment: Where are the error details? Did you miss staving the image or pasting the error

Comment: in my case, it started working after i TURNED ON instant run, strange...it was giving the error when the instant run was turned off.

Comment: In my case just cleaning the project worked! Phew!

Comment: I will second that "Build->Clean Project" solved this issue for me, as well.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

You can use normal build run rather than instant run.

Check first

Go to *Settings/Preferences* > *Build, Execution, Deployment option* > *Instant Run* and **uncheck** all the three boxes.

1. Upgrading Gradle services URL:

   Project > Gradle > Wrapper > gradle-wrapper.properties

   Change URL from

   ```
   distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip
   ```

   to

   ```
   distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.11-all.zip
   ```

(Find latest distributionUrl gradle plugin version Here: http://services.gradle.org/distributions

**Make sure to use gradle-x.xx-all.zip
)

2. Delete your build folder

   When you run project, build folder will be created automatically
3. Go to BUILD option in menu > Clean the project, Build the project

   It should work without instant run.

Comment: thanks for explaining in answers as steps. checking settings and step1 are mandatory ones in order to get rid out of this error

Comment: @Manju When I met the error, step 1 and settings are needed.

Comment: This is a good answer, but is there a way to still use instant run?

Comment: @me1982 Yes! Update your android studio to latest version or Download a fresh edition

Comment: I am using the latest version. This started happening because I updated to the latest.

Comment: All steps were necessary for me to get out of this error (AS 2.1.2 on a Mac)

Comment: Funny enough, not all steps were necessary for me to get out of this error (AS 2.1.2 on a Mac) – 1) clean project 2) update gradle from 2.12 to 2.14.1

Comment: Just add a data point. The latest IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.4 is not happy with the latest Gradle 3.1. Gradle 2.14.1 is fine.

Comment: Cleaning was enough for me Gradle > :app > build > clean

Comment: I didn't disabled the instant run and it worked for me!

Comment: Got this error in 3.3 version. Update to 3.5 itself is working though the current one is 4.1

Answer (score 33):

I had easy steps & correct way also

1 - In `Settings` -> `Build, Execution, Deployment` option -> `Instant Run`

2 - Clear `Enable instant run to hot swap code`

3 - Clean project

p/s : It should totally work.

Answer (score 21):

The Gradle Plugin used is typically the same as the version of Android studio you are using.

Check the Android Studio version

> Help  → About

and the version will read 
`Android Studio Version X.Y.Z`

Then, go to

> Project  → Gradle Scripts  → build.gradle(Project)

and under dependencies change the classpath to

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:X.Y.Z'`

and rebuild/sync the project.

Answer (score 8):

You can disable instant run by follow these steps in Android Studio:

> File → Settings → Preferences dialog → Build → Execution → Deployment
>   → Instant Run → Update Project

This feature introduced in Android Studio 2. however, when you disable it, next time when you try to push new app to your emulator is running much slower.

In my case I just update Android Studio to the latest build from canary channel and it's works without disable this feature.

Hope it's help

Comment: If you don't want to update Android Studio, you can also adjust the gradle version number like in John Snow's answer.

Answer (score 8):

As commented by sjd: Just cleaning the project and build again might help if you, just like me, have used the automatic update applied by android studio.

Comment: This worked for me.  Much better solution than disabling instant run, if available.

Answer (score 7):

I just did a Build > Clean project and then reRun app!

Comment: made my day!! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to run the app in debug mode and got the same message, so I tried:

- File > Invalidate caches and restart...
- Clean project
- Build project

Nothing worked...

Then, I just clicked on the green arrow to run the project without debugging...

Worked!

So then I just added a debugging session with the option left of the stop button in Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I did fix by this way.

Update your classpath to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'` in your **top level** **build.gradle** file.

**Done**

Answer (score 0):

I just **Deleted** the **Build** Folder and **Clean project**.It worked for me...!!!

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio 2.3.3

File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Instant Run -> Unable Instant Run to hot swap code (Uncheck it)

Now, you have disable Instant Run...

It will solve Instant Run issue.