# Version of Android Studio is incompatible with the Gradle Plugin used

Tags: android, gradle, gradle-plugin

When trying to run application on my device (or emulated device) I constantly getting same error:

```
Error running app: This version of Android Studio is incompatible with the Gradle Plugin used. Try disabling Instant Run (or updating either the IDE or the Gradle plugin to the latest version)
```

After successful gradle build.

I was trying some Gradle settings - *Use default Gradle wrapper*, or *Use Gradle wrapper task configuration* - no changes.

gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-bin.zip
```

build.gradle

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha6'
```

It's open source project from github. No one else complaining about this.

I was working on Ubuntu 15.10, so gradle --version command could be useful informaction,

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 1.5
------------------------------------------------------------

Gradle build time: niedziela, 16 listopad 2014 16:24:40 UTC
Groovy: 1.8.6
Ant: Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.4 compiled on January 27 2015
Ivy: non official version
JVM: 1.7.0_95 (Oracle Corporation 24.95-b01)
```

**EDIT:** Ohh, I tried to disable *Instant Run* in configuration as well.
**EDIT2:** I don't have problems with another project which I was working on simultaneonusly, but every settings are the same, so I really don't know what to do.

Comment: what is the gradle version of your android studio and the one you are using in your project

Comment: I'm not using Anroid Studio at all - It's statement from Intellij Idea - it's really confusing

Comment: Clean the project and delete the build folder... That may solve the issue. And also look at [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35549545/1332892).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue may be caused by a IDE/Gradle bug! Try switching the Gradle version to the latest one or by downgrading to a stable release,

> Latest version: **2.2.0-beta2**
>
> Last stable version: **2.1.3**

You can try other versions too, [check here](https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.android.tools.build.gradle/view)!

Comment: Works like charm with com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3 - thanks a lot