# Error running app: This version of Android Studio is incompatible with the Gradle Plugin used

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, instant-run

I'm working with multiple projects provided from a Git repo and none of them work without disabling the instant run or changing the Gradle plugin. I get the following error:

```
Error running app: This version of Android Studio is incompatible with the Gradle Plugin used.Try disabling Instant Run (or updating either the IDE or the Gradle plugin to the latest version)
```

My question is what would be the lowest Gradle plugin that would function with instant run to solve this error? I am using Android Studio 2.2.3.

Comment: what is your android studio version?

Comment: Android Studio 2.2.3

Comment: Android plugin for Gradle version 2.0.0 or higher required for instant run

Comment: I am currently on classpath  'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0-alpha1'

Comment: generally gradle classpath is same as your studio version

Comment: 2.3.0 will not work in your case as your Android Studio is not updated to 2.3 version

Comment: Just changed to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'` and the error was fixed. thanks for the clarification

Comment: I think you should refer this answer [stackoverflow.com/questions/this-version-of-android-studio-is-incompatible-with-the-gradle-version-used-try](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35202541/this-version-of-android-studio-is-incompatible-with-the-gradle-version-used-try)