# Intellij: This version of android studio is incompatible with the gradle version used.Try disabling the instant run

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle

First, I just moved to using Intellij Idea from Android Studio [So, this question is NOT a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35202541/this-version-of-android-studio-is-incompatible-with-the-gradle-version-used-try).]. Now, I am able to build the app properly, but when I run it I get this error:

```
This version of android studio is incompatible with the gradle version used. Try disabling the instant run
```

Is there a way to fix this without disabling instant run?

Additional info: 
My top level build.gradle has this dependency:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'
```

Intellij Idea version is :

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.1
Build #IC-171.4073.35, built on April 6, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-736-b16 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Linux 4.10.0-19-generic
```

Comment: Please [see the answer](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000157770-When-will-Idea-2017-catch-up-with-the-current-Android-gradle-plugin-) to the similar question in IntelliJ IDEA forum.

Comment: Obviously it's not the best solution but as a work around you can disable Instant Run. The link that @CrazyCoder provided mentions they are releasing a fix in ~2 weeks.