# android studio: error running app

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

while running my app, i got BUILD SUCCESSFUL, 0 errors, 0 warrnings but the ide is showing a red message running message about android studio and gradle version even though i'm using the latest version of both of them.

**here's the error message:**

> Error running app: this version of Android Studio is incompatible with the Gradle Plugin used. Try disabling Instant Run (or updating either the IDE or the Gradle plugin to the latest version)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You gotta do 3 things:

1. Upgrading Gradle services URL
2. Delete your build folder
3. Go to BUILD option in menu > Clean the project, Build the project

For more details on how to do all of this, go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35202541/this-version-of-android-studio-is-incompatible-with-the-gradle-version-used-try).

Answer (score 1):

Please check you gradle version is compatible with android studio version ..

```
Plugin version     Required Gradle version
1.0.0 - 1.1.3      2.2.1 - 2.3
1.2.0 - 1.3.1      2.2.1 - 2.9
1.5.0              2.2.1 - 2.13
2.0.0 - 2.1.2      2.10 - 2.13
2.1.3 - 2.2.3      2.14.1+
2.3.0+             3.3+
```

for more detail you can read android doc [Link](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html)

Answer (score 0):

What version of Gradle do you have as a dependency in your Project's build.gradle? I think the newest version is gradle:2.3.3 (that's what I'm running at least), and if you don't have that version as a dependency you might just be using an out of date version even if it says you're up to date.

Comment: the latest version of grale is 4.0.1 and i'm using it! @Nutters